# How can MDX query take parameters to filter by Fact Table datetime attribute

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube, sql-server-data-tools

We have a fact table that has a datetime field [Log Entry].[Time Entry].

We would like to  filter the following query based on a date range:  where the [Log Entry].[Time Entry] was between two supplied dates (2 parameters: i.e. startdate and enddate)

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Average Total Time] } ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY { ([User Property].[UserProperty].[Id].ALLMEMBERS * [Log Entry].[Time Entry].[Logged On].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM [MyCube]
```

I was hoping to avoid having to create Time Table/dimension and being able to compare those dates (passed in via parameters) against the [Log Entry].[Time Entry].

Concept of SQL's between (somedate Between date1 and date2).

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use range expression. Please look here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Your WHERE clause should look for example:

```
  WHERE (
    [Time].[Month Name].&[August 2009]
    :
    [Time].[Month Name].&[June 2012]
    )
```

**UPDATE**
To Filter Axis inside it, you should use EXISTS clause:

```
    * {EXISTS
   (
      {[Log Entry].[Time Entry].[Logged On].ALLMEMBERS}
    ,
    {[Log Entry].[Time Entry].&[20120101]:[Log Entry].[Time Entry].&[20130101]}
    )
```

Comment: Dalex - thanks for the suggestions.  However, I don't see how this range makes an association with the field that actually has the value to compare in the range.